# Cannot use variable in default parameters of a method

Tags: ruby

Can I use variables in default parameters of a method ? If not, then why ? This is in ruby 1.8.7

```
var = "one"

def sysout(str=var)
  puts str
end

sysout("seven")
sysout()
```

Error -

```
seven
test.rb:3:in `sysout': undefined local variable or method `var' for main:Object (NameError)
        from test.rb:8
```

Comment: If you have the choice, you should not use 1.8.7. It's been sunsetted for 18 months. The current version is 2.2.0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use *any* arbitrary Ruby expression as the default argument value for an optional parameter, there are absolutely no restrictions what you can put in there. It can be as simple as a single lone literal or as complex as an entire application. (Although I wouldn't recommend the latter.)

But Ruby's scoping rules don't just magically disappear. Local variables are still local variables, global variables are still global variables, and so on.

Blocks are the only things in Ruby which create nested scopes, so you have to use a block:

```
var = 'one'

define_method(:sysout) do |str=var|
  puts str
end

sysout('seven')
# seven

sysout
# one
```

Alternatively, you could make the default value a method:

```
def var; 'one' end

def sysout(str=var)
  puts str
end

sysout('seven')
# seven

sysout
# one
```

Or a global variable:

```
$var = 'one'

def sysout(str=$var)
  puts str
end

sysout('seven')
# seven

sysout
# one
```

Comment: Thanks Jorg. Can you please explain these lines (1) define_method(:sysout)  (2) def var; 'one' end. Thanks

Comment: (1) calls the method `define_method` passing the symbol `:sysout` and a block as an argument. You can probably guess what `define_method` does from its name, if not, just look up its documentation. (2) In Ruby, methods are defined with the `def` keyword, so this defines a method named `var`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use variables, but the local variable `var` that you defined does not share the scope with the argument position of `sysout`'s method definition.